# Favorite Tags return old data

Tags: support, tag-watching

I've got a couple of issues when browsing my favorite tags over at stackexchange.com that includes results from the various Stack Exchange sites that I participate in.

- Certain sites are completely left out of the results. At this moment, all questions from Stack Overflow are left out, but questions from Code Review and others are in there.
- I often get very old results that doesn't show the latest questions. These can range from an hour old results up to a couple of days old results.

These issues vary from time-to-time, an hour ago everything was working fine, but now and earlier this morning there were issues. This has been going on for months now on and off, but today seems to be more problematic than usual.

I can't see any ongoing issues over at http://stackstatus.net/.

Comment: cross-site related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308248/filtered-questions-not-showing-any-questions-from-sites-where-i-want-to-see-all